# PyQt4 Gui (QlistWidget)

Tags: python, user-interface, qlistwidget

im currently working on a python project which uses a Gui (Pyqt4) to display sets of information in a user friendly format.I have already created the Gui which has a list Widget, the problem is im not sure how to add a list of Tv channels Ive obtained from an Api and display it in the listwidget in python 3.3.4.
Any help will be very much appreciated
Thanks

**Update**

`self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(65, 181, 371, 371))
 self.listWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listWidget")) 
 item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()`

I am not sure how to display the information I obtained from bbc1 API in #this `Qlistwidget` using a loop `for I in bbc1: print`

Comment: what code have you tied yet ?

Comment: @Shanoop so far I have  self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(65, 181, 371, 371))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listWidget"))
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        # not sure how to display the information i obtained from bbc1 api in
        #this Qlistwidget using a loop
        for i in bbc1: 
             print ???????

Comment: I don't know how to display the code in this comment box I a better format

Comment: you can use edit option and Stackoverflow uses Markdown for all inputs. So you can use markdown code to format correctly. 
https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet